# How to get field type and value in same order using Reflection API?

Tags: java, methods, reflection, field

I have the following Student class

```java
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Student {
    @Id
    private int studentId;
    private int groupId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    // getter setter
}
```

What I am trying to do is to get the field value and the field type through reflection. And put the result into list. The field value is retrieved through `Field#get` and the type is retrieved through `Method#getReturnType` of the getter, as shown below.

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MethodFieldOrder {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student entity = new Student();
        entity.setGroupId(1);
        entity.setFirstName("Jackson");
        entity.setLastName("Romanovich");
        List<String> valuesToInsert = new ArrayList<>();
        Field[] field = entity.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field1 : field) {
            field1.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                Object value = field1.get(entity);
                valuesToInsert.add(value.toString());
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        valuesToInsert.remove(0);
        Method[] methods = entity.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
        List<String> returnTypes = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Method method : methods) {
            if (method.getName().startsWith("get") || method.getName().startsWith("is")) {
                returnTypes.add(String.valueOf(method.getReturnType()));
            }
        }
        returnTypes.remove(0);
        System.out.println("Values to insert : " + valuesToInsert);
        System.out.println("RETURN TYPES  : " + returnTypes);
        // Values to insert : [1, Jackson, Romanovich]
        // RETURN TYPES  : [int, int, class java.lang.String]
        // What I want is: [int, class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String]
    }
}
```

As shown in the program, the problem is the order of fields `entity.getClass().getDeclaredFields()` is not consistent with the order of `entity.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()`. How can I make sure field value list and field type list have same ordering?

Comment: I can't reproduce "I do the same with `Methods[]` I get data in the different orders", please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @samabcde I have added the array Methods[] 
I accept entity value and need to get all return types of this entity.
I know how to get it but I receive it in the different order every time

Comment: @samabcde The same - I mean that with Field[] when I try to invoke data from entity is work but with Methods[] it works not properly

Comment: As a side note, it's weird that you use `value.toString()` when `value` can be `null`, but `String.valueOf(method.getReturnType())` where `method.getReturnType()` is guaranteed to never be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

As per [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html), both `getFields()` and `getMethods()` mention the following:

> The elements in the returned array are not sorted and are not in any particular order.

So, you don't have any guarantee about the order of the `Field`s or `Method`s in the returned array. If the order is important for you, or you just want a constant order, you have to sort yourself. In your example, you use a `List` to hold field values and method return types. One solution is to use a `TreeSet` so that your collections have always the same order, no matter how the `Field[]` or `Method[]` arrays you get are ordered.

Comment: You did not undestand me, if I use Set it will not have the same values, but I need it.
I have wrong order even if  `Method[] methods = entity.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
 for (Method method : methods) { system.out.println(method.getReturnType()};`

So I suppose it's not the mistake in the collection.

Comment: What I wanted to say is that `getDeclaredMethods` doesn't make any guarantee about the order of the `Method`s in the returned array. If you need a particular order, or just a constant one, you have to sort them yourself.

Comment: @Mary, Dan is explaining that the `methods[]` returned by `getDeclaredMethods()` has *no defined* ordering(Not according to method declared order in class). Can you put an example of entity class and the current output to clarify we you need?

Comment: @samabcde Added to the post

Comment: @Mary, I guess you are trying to get entity field value and corresponding type for inserting, why don't you use `Field.getType` to produce consistent ordering?

Comment: Or even better, invoke the setter method instead of accessing private fields. There is no guaranty that a getter method has a corresponding field at all and not every field is indented to be exposed.